# Azure machine learning webservice deployment failed

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

Deployment error to ACS - BadRequestFormat. How do I get past this? This is my nth attempt to make the tutorial work end to end https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/preview/tutorial-classifying-iris-part-1.

az ml env setup -n gopenv --location westcentralus -c

Subscription set to Visual Studio Premium with MSDN

Continue with this subscription (Y/n)? y

Resource group gopenvrg already exists, skipping creation.

creating service principal.........done

Created a service principal: %s 96f6dd9e-c9d6-4856-9f8b-5426c7a757ea

waiting for AAD role to propagate.done

Provisioning compute resources...

BadRequestFormat: The request format was invalid. Details: Updating clusters with cluster type Local is not supported

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when I ran the command again after it had already run successfully once. Considering that your output says, "Resource group gopenvrg already exists", it looks like that might be true for you too.

If you change "-n gopenv" to something else like "-n gopenv2", it might work for you. It did for me.

You can see if you already have any deployment environments by running "az ml env list".